# What is the probability that if three dice are thrown that the maximum number shown is $5$?

Tags: probability, statistics

'You throw $3$ regular $6$-sided dice. What is the probability that the one (or *the ones*) that show the maximum amount of "eyes" show $5$?'

Can't seem to get my head around this one. Unsure on where to start, thankful for any help!

Comment: The word die is singular; the word dice is plural; the word dices means to cut into small cubes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be formulated differently, which might hint to a solution: what is the probability that you get no $6$, and at least one $5$?

The probability of none of the dice showing a $6$ is $(5/6)^3$.

Given that you have gotten no $6$, the probability of getting at least one $5$ is the opposite of the probability of no $5$. The probability of no $5$ given that there are no $6$ is $(4/5)^3$. Therefore the probability of at least one $5$ is $1-(4/5)^3$.

The total probability is therefore
$$
\left(\frac56\right)^3\left(1-\left(\frac45\right)^3\right)
$$